# Number of users shown in play store listing and its update period

Tags: android

I have two questions regarding the number of users shown for a mobile app in play store.

1. Does the number of users include all the countries or just include users from whatever country you are viewing it from?
2. How frequent does this number update?

Comment: this question is off topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows total number of downloads in all countries and it updates daily. But the time at which it is updated varies, at least for my apps.